# Can you have a column of dataframes in pyspark?

Tags: nested, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am a little new to pyspark/bigdata so this could be a bad idea, but I have about a million individual CSV files each associated with some metadata. I would like a pyspark dataframe with columns for all the metadata fields, but also with a column whose entries are the (whole) CSV files associated with each set of metadata.

I am not at work right now but I remember almost the exact code. I have tried a toy example something like

```
outer_pandas_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[4,5,6]})

##    A  B
## 0  1  4
## 1  2  5
## 2  3  6
```

And then if you do

```
outer_schema = StructType([
    StructField("A", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("B", IntegerType(), True)
])

outer_spark_df = sqlctx.createDataFrame(outer_pandas_df, schema=outer_schema)
```

Then the result is a spark dataframe as expected. But now if you do

```
inner_pandas_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"W":["X","Y","Z"]})
outer_pandas_df["C"] = [inner_pandas_df, inner_pandas_df, inner_pandas_df]
```

And make the schema like

```
inner_schema = StructType([
    StructField("W", StringType(), True)
])

outer_schema = StructType([
    StructField("A", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("B", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("W", ArrayType(inner_schema), True)
])
```

then this fails:

```
sqlctx.createDataFrame(outer_pandas_df, schema=outer_schema)
```

with an error related to ArrayType not accepting pandas dataframes. I don't have the exact error.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Answer (score 0):

Spark does not support nested dataframes. Why do you want a column that contains the entire CSV to be constantly stored in memory, anyway? It seems to me that if you need that, you are not successfully extracting the data into the other columns.